# Suspected issues with disposing Excel objects causing subsequent selenium tests to fail?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, dispose

I've created several Selenium tests in C# for testing a login page.  Each test uses a different pair of credentials sourced from the same Excel spreadsheet, and each runs great by itself.  I found a great bit of code on the web for being able to read the Excel spreadsheet and locating the data in a specific row for use.  The problem that I'm running into is that the tests only run to completion in isolation and not when they are run in a series.  In the latter case, only the first one succeeds whereas all the subsequent tests fail with a "text cannot be null" exception.  I am suspicious that it could be something to do with Excel not getting disposed of properly between each test.  Any ideas on how I can properly clean up the Excel stuff?

Here is the code where I instantiate the Excel object:

```
string path1 =     Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,     @"SeleniumData\LoginBook.xlsx");
ExcelLib loginBook = new ExcelLib(path1);
```

Here is where I call the workbook:

```
rmMain_PageObject pageRMMain = new     rmLogin_PageObject().Login(loginBook.ReadData(1, "UserName"),     (loginBook.ReadData(1, "Password")));
```

Here is the method itself:

```
        using Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoTestProject1
{
    public class ExcelLib
    {
        private  DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
        {
            //open file and returns as Stream
            FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            //Createopenxmlreader via ExcelReaderFactory
            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); //.xlsx
            //Set the First Row as Column Name
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            //Return as DataSet
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
            //Get all the Tables
            DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
            //Store it in DataTable
            DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];

            //return
            return resultTable;
        }

        public ExcelLib(string fileName)
        {
            PopulateInCollection(fileName);
        }
        public class Datacollection
        {
            public int rowNumber { get; set; }
            public int colNumber { get; set; }                              //test
            public string colName { get; set; }
            public string colValue { get; set; }
        }

        static List<Datacollection> dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();

        private  void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
        {
            DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);

            //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
            for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                //for (int col = 0; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
                    {
                        rowNumber = row,
                        colNumber = col,                                        //test
                        colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                        colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                    };
                    //Add all the details for each row
                    dataCol.Add(dtTable);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var excelObject = new ExcelObject //what ever excel assy you are using
try{
}
catch(Exception e){
}
finally{
   excelObject.Dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: Please, try to provide explanation with your answer, not just code